# Unable to export product .csv file

Tags: magento2

Hi am trying to export a product csv file but am not getting a file as does not appear and when i export the file i get this message **messeage is added to queue,wait to get you file soon** and i never get it..

i have also run all the commands

```
php bin/magento setup:di:comlile

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

and cache flush
but issue seem to remain please help me its urjent am still a learner in magento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi please run this commands from magetno root and it will solve your issue

```
bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor
```

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: Thank you this works you helped me again thank you chikku

Comment: no problem just keep learning and exploring new things in magento

Answer (score 0):

```
php bin/magento queue:consumer:start exportProcessor
```

This command initiates the export processor consumer, which is responsible for handling product exports through the Magento message queue system.